# I have a POST request to add users. I don't want to be able to add the same user twice. How could I add this functionality

Tags: node.js

I'm learning node by building a simple phonebook app. I have added the ability to add users and ensure that both name and number is added before fulfilling post request.

My question is, how would I prevent the post action if either name or number is already in phonebook and to prompt user to choose another name.

Here is my current post request:

```
let persons = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Arto Hellas',
    number: '010-111111'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ada Lovelace',
    number: '440-123456'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Dan Abramov',
    number: '330-349994'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Mary Poppendieck',
    number: '210-113578'
  }
];

app.post('/persons', (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;

  if (body.name === undefined) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: 'content missing'
    });
  }

  if (body.number === undefined) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: 'content missing'
    });
  }
  const person = {
    name: body.name,
    number: body.number,
    id: generateId()
  };
  persons = persons.concat(person);

  res.json(person);
});
```

Struggling to wrap my head around it.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to check if the user is already In `persons`

Comment: Yes persons is my array contacts. I'll edit to show now.

Comment: Also be mindful that you may get multiple requests at the same time, and how you might need to think about checking for duplicate users in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example with a static array of objects, it's just a matter of checking if the user already exists in the array, but in a real world situation, you'll be working with an actual database. Depending on the type of database you choose, you could either have constraints on the columns, or you could check if the value exists already before inserting, or do both.

If you just want to check the array of objects, as in your example, it would be much easier to check if the object value exists in any of the objects using [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which allows you to define a function for testing the elements.

Live demo:

```js
let persons = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Arto Hellas',
    number: '010-111111'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ada Lovelace',
    number: '440-123456'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Dan Abramov',
    number: '330-349994'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Mary Poppendieck',
    number: '210-113578'
  }
];

const name = 'Dan Abramov';
const number = '210-113570';

if (!persons.some(e => e.name === name || e.number === number)) {
  console.log("does not exist");
} else {
  console.log("exists");
}
```

And in the context of your example:

```
let persons = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Arto Hellas',
        number: '010-111111'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Ada Lovelace',
        number: '440-123456'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Dan Abramov',
        number: '330-349994'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Mary Poppendieck',
        number: '210-113578'
    }
];

app.post('/persons', (req, res) => {
    const { name, number } = req.body;

    if (!name || !number) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'content missing'
        });
    }

    if (!persons.some(e => e.name === name || e.number === number)) {
        const person = {
            name,
            number,
            id: generateId()
        };
        persons = persons.concat(person);

        res.json(person);
    }
    else {
        //person name and/or person number was already in persons
    }
});
```

You'll notice I also simplified the request body checks as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add the checking coding before concate the `person` JSON object, like following:-

```
var valid = true;
for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++){
  if (persons[i].name == body.name || persons[i].number == body.number ){
    valid = false;
    break;
  }
}

if(valid){
    //perform person concat
}else{
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: 'Person name or number duplicated, Please choose another name or number'
    });
}
```